# How to append content to stringstream type object?

Tags: c++

i am using object of stringstream as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    sting str="my.string";

    std::stringstream message("HI this is firet line from initialization");

    message << " second line " << " Continuing second line";

    message << ", Add values: ";

    message << str ;


    std::cout<<"message value is :"<<message.str()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

with above code it gives an error as follows:

```
 error: variable 'std::stringstream message' has initializer but incomplete type
```

above error is resolved once i added the "#include " header file. but when i printed the value of message. it is getting incomplete. i.e. value i got of message is as follows:

message value is :  second line  Continueing second linetion , Add values: my.string

any suggestion on why first line is removing in output?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try including <sstream> header.

Comment: did you try `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: always post compilable code. `sting` is not valid in this context.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`stringstream` is defined in a different header:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Also, if you want the initial contents to stick you'll want something like:

```
std::stringstream message("HI this is firet line from initialization",
                                             ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
```

where `app` means that every output operation writes to the end of the stream. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/stringstream/).

Comment: Thanks Vlad very much.... i got resolved error as well as got the correct contain.

Comment: Excellent answer! Just what I needed. See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Answer (score 17):

Following Vlad's answer, I just tried the following (in GCC 4.7.0, mingw on Windows 7: x86_64-w64-mingw32)

```
std::stringstream ss("initial string", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
ss << " appended string";
```

But afterward, `ss.good()` would return false immediately afterward, which was confusing, since `ss.str()` was still returning the appended string I expected, `"initial string appended string"`.  I finally stumbled upon the following line from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/:

> Other values of type ios_base::openmode (such as ios_base::app) may also be specified, although whether they have an effect on stringstream objects depends on the library implementation.

After reading about the "standard" `ios_base::` flags, I tried this, which gave me the appended stream contents I expected, with `ss.good()` returning `true`:

```
std::stringstream ss("initial string", ios_base::ate | ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

[P.S.  I would rather have posted this as a comment on Vlad's answer, since it's not a direct answer; it's only a comment on his suggestion for preserving previous stream contents when using `operator <<`.  Since I don't have enough reputation points to comment on his answer, but I think this will be useful to others who come across this, I'm posting it as an answer.]