# How to append string to istringstream?

Tags: c++, iostream, istringstream

A websocket server receives messages that need to pass to a function as an `std::istream`. I am using a `istringstream` as an intermediate step as:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream, std::stringbuf
#include <string>
...
std::istringstream _iss;
std::istream &_inputbuff = _iss;
```

My message handler receives the message as a string and sets `_iss.str(message)`.

This approach does not update the stream with the new blocks of data and as a result the next function samples only the last packet. Is there a way to append to the `istringstream` instead of setting?

Thank you

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786183/how-to-append-content-to-stringstream-type-object) it looks like you'll want to set certain flags in the sstream constructor. See also the [mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) parameter.

Comment: `std::istringstream` is a read-only stream (hence the `i` in its name, meaning **input**), so it does not allow for appending new characters once the stream has been created.  `std::stringstream`, on the other hand, is a read/write stream. You can append characters using `operator<<`, `put()`, etc and then read them back out as needed.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau, this actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `std::stringstream` and use `put(...)` function for incoming data (to fill your buffer) and later consume it as you are doing.

`stringstream` STL reference:
https://cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/