# Why doesn't std::stringstream work with std::string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, istringstream, string-view

The `std::stringstream` *initialization constructor* accepts `const string&` as a parameter:

```cpp
explicit stringstream (const string& str,
                       ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

This interface was reasonable in C++98, but since C++17 we have `std::string_view` as a cheaper alternative of the class representing a string. The `std::stringstream` class doesn't modify the string it accepts, doesn't own it, it doesn't require from it to be null-terminated. So why not to add another constructor overload that accepts the `std::string_view`? Are there any obstacles that make this solution impossible (or not reasonable) yielding to alternatives like *Boost::Iostreams*?

Comment: Likely because it just wasn't added. Nobody wrote the proposal, so it wasn't done. There many other places where this wasn't done: exception constructors, for example.

Comment: @StaceyGirl, that looks like an obvious answer, but it is strange to me that nothing is proposed to fix the issue even in C++23 (as far as I know).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this point (ie: as we approach C++23), there's just not much point to it.

Since you used `stringstream` instead of one of the more usage-specific versions, there are two possibilities: you either intend to be able to write to the stream, or you don't.

If you don't intend to write to the stream, then you don't need the data to be copied. All forms of `stringstream` own the characters it acts on, so you should try to avoid the copy. You can use the C++23 type `ispanstream` (a replacement for the old `strstream`). This takes a `span<const CharT>`, but `string_view` [should be compatible with one of `ispanstream`'s constructors too](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ispanstream/basic_ispanstream).

If you do intend to write to the stream, then you will need to copy the data into the `stringstream`. But you need not perform two copies. So C++20 gives `stringstream` a move-constructor from a `std::string`. See [constructor #6 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream):

```cpp
explicit basic_stringstream( std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>&& str,
                             std::ios_base::openmode mode = 
                             std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out );
```

> 6. Move-construct the contents of the underlying string device with `str`. The underlying `basic_stringbuf` object is constructed as `basic_stringbuf<Char,Traits,Allocator>(std::move(str), mode)`.

And since `std::string` is constructable from a `string_view`, passing a `std::string_view` into a `std::stringstream` constructor will use this move-constructor overload, which should minimize copying.

So there's really no need for a `string_view`-specific constructor.

Answer (score 0):

### How to efficiently (with `std::move()` if you like) construct a `std::stringstream` from a `std::string`, `std::string_view`, or C-string in C++11 or later

### Quick summary

```cpp
std::string str("Hello ");                            // std::string
constexpr char c_str[] = "Hey and how are you ";      // C-string
std::string_view sv(c_str);                           // std::string_view

std::stringstream ss1(str);                           // from a std::string
std::stringstream ss3(std::move(std::string(c_str))); // from a C-string
std::stringstream ss2(std::move(std::string(sv)));    // from a std::string_view
```

### Details

I just updated [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589650/4561887) by @Nicol Bolas with the C++20 move-constructor (constructor #6) definition and explanation from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream. If you're using C++11, however, you can still get this efficiency boost (as far as I can tell) simply by calling `std::move()` yourself.

With or without explicitly calling `std::move()`, all 3 techniques below work to construct a `std::stringstream` since C++11. **So, having an extra constructor from `std::string_view` really isn't necessary, since you can *already* construct a `std::stringstream` from a `std::string`, from a `std::string_view`, or from a C-string (`char` array), as shown below.**

You can play with some test examples like these in my [stringstream_initialize_from_std_string__string_view__and_c_string.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/stringstream_initialize_from_std_string__string_view__and_c_string.cpp) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

```cpp
std::string str("Hello ");                          // std::string
constexpr char c_str[] = "Hey and how are you ";    // C-string
std::string_view sv(c_str);                         // std::string_view

// 1. Construct a `std::stringstream` from a `std::string`. This is
// constructor #3 from the link below: reference page for the
// `std::stringstream` constructors:
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream
// - Open in mode `std::ios_base::app` as well in order to **append** all new
//   writes to the end of the stream! See link above **and**:
//   https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786212/4561887
std::stringstream ss1(str, 
    std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
ss1 << "world.\n";  // since `std::ios_base::app` was used above, this 
                    // **appends** rather than **overwrites** the data in 
                    // the stringstream.
std::cout << ss1.str() << "\n";

// 2. Construct a `std::stringstream` from a `std::string_view`. This is also
// constructor #3 from the link above (passing in a `std::string), but we must
// first construct a `std::string` from the `std::string_view`. We are using
// constructor #10 from the `std::string` constructors shown here to create a
// `std::string` from a `std::string_view`:
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string
// - See also the note about the `std::ios_base::app` mode above.
std::stringstream ss2b(std::move(std::string(sv)),
    std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
ss2b << "today?\n";
std::cout << ss2b.str() << "\n";

// 3. Construct a `std::stringstream` from a C-string. This is also
// constructor #3 from the link above (passing in a `std::string), but we must
// first construct a `std::string` from the C-string. We are using
// constructor #5 from the `std::string` constructors shown here to create a
// `std::string` from a C-string (`const char*`):
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string
// - See also the note about the `std::ios_base::app` mode above. Note that the
//   C-string is used to automatically, implicitly construct a `std::string`
//   here, I believe.
//
// implicit construction of `std::string` from `c_str`
std::stringstream ss3c(std::move(c_str),
    std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
ss3c << "doing?\n";
std::cout << ss3c.str();
// explicit construction of `std::string` from `c_str`
std::stringstream ss3d(std::move(std::string(c_str)),
    std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
ss3d << "doing?\n";
std::cout << ss3d.str();
```

Sample output:

```
Hello world.
Hey and how are you today?
Hey and how are you doing?
Hey and how are you doing?
```

### References

1. `std::stringstream` constructors: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream
2. constructor #10 from the `std::string` constructors shown here to create a `std::string` from a `std::string_view`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

   1. and constructor #5 from the `std::string` constructors shown here to create a `std::string` from a C-string (`const char*`)
3. [How to append content to stringstream type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786212/4561887)

Comment: `std::stringstream ss2(std::move(std::string(str)));   // from a std::string_view` Did you mean `sv` instead of `str`?

Comment: Those two `std::move`s are unnecessary: `std::stringstream ss3(std::move(std::string(c_str)));` You don't need to do that for an rvalue. Only lvalues need to be `move`ed.